# Export Map Error from OpenLayers 3 in Chrome?

Tags: chrome, mapcanvas, openlayers

Im using this [js file](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/export-map.js) to export map in Openlayers 3 in Google Chrome but i'm getting en error saying that `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.` I also set an cross Origin attribute as anonymous. The function of export button is as follow

```
var exportPNGElement = document.getElementById('export-png');
exportPNGElement.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    if ('download' in exportPNGElement) {
      exportPNGElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        map.once('postcompose', function(event) {
          var canvas = event.context.canvas;
          exportPNGElement.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        });
        map.renderSync();
      }, false);
    } else {
      var info = document.getElementById('no-download');
      /**
       * display error message
       */
      info.style.display = '';
    }
```

Comment: This is a CORS problem of your images consisting your map. What sort of layers exist within the image you are trying to export?

Comment: My layers consists of administrative boundaries and I enabled CORS extension in Chrome!

Comment: You have to enable CORS on the server side. Enable it on client doesnt help. I am asking the type of layer , is it geoserver for example? If yes you have to enable CORS on geoserver side.

Answer (score 2):

try adding **crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'** to the layer sources !

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it something like that:

```
function exportPNGElement() {
    map.once('postcompose', function(event) {
      var canvas = event.context.canvas;
      if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        navigator.msSaveBlob(canvas.msToBlob(), 'map.png');
      } else {
        canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
          saveAs(blob, 'map.png');
        });
      }
    });
    map.renderSync();
  };
```

Comment: I tried this one also but  same error..

Comment: @Hyma I am working with this function and it works in all browsers, try to check your code. (why your canvas is tainted)